# Execute a Command On A Collection Of Items, Functionally

Tags: .net, vb.net, functional-programming

I've done a little bit of LINQ but I almost exclusively return some elements from a collection based on some criteria.  Now I'm trying to do something similar; let's say I have 50 winForm Controls in a collection - I want to set the .Visible property = True based on the controls name.

How would I do that?  Below is my failed attempt.

```
myControls.AsEnumerable.Select( Function (myControl as Control) ( myControl.Visible = (myControl.Name <> "Hidden")) )
```

It compiles and even executes but does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a foreach

```
myControls.AsEnumerable.ToList().ForEach(Sub (myControl as Control) ( myControl.Visible = (myControl.Name <> "Hidden")) )
```